# Where can i find NSSearchField and NSTableView tutorials for Cocoa?

Tags: macos

I'm just a new baby in Cocoa.
But i have some experience in iOS.

I want NSSearchField and NSTableView tutorials for Cocoa like dictionary application on Mac OSX Lion.
Where can i find it?

I already googling , but i didn't found anything.
Is there tutorials like that? If please guide me there.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first time, you can find sample Cocoa Tutorials in Apple's developer website.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/NSTableViewBinding/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010522) is the sample tutorials for NSTableView